# Problem with conditional trigger (or animation)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseEnterToDocumentsMenu">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Documents">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0.8"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseLeaveFromDocumentsMenu">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Documents">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0.3"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseEnterToPeopleMenu">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="People">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0.8"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseLeaveFromPeopleMenu">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="People">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0.3"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter" SourceName="Documents">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseEnterToDocumentsMenu}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave" SourceName="Documents">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseLeaveFromDocumentsMenu}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter" SourceName="People">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseEnterToPeopleMenu}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave" SourceName="People">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseLeaveFromPeopleMenu}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
```

**Purpose**

I'm animation a Menu. Menu elements are TextBlocks, I'm simulating a "Hover fading".

**Problem**

The code I posted animates the opacity once the mouse enter or leave. I have another method (code behind) that sets to "1" the opacity of the menu element once the user clicks it on the menu (and load the appropriate user control on its respective container). I guess this method is working, **BUT** once the MouseLeave animation start it fades the opacity again no matter if that element was selected or not (If its opacity was 1 not 0.8).

**Needs**

Is there a way to specify that the MouseLeave trigger fires only when the Source Opacity is not 1. Or to execute the storyboard only if the TargetProperty is not 1.

Thanks.

**PS**

Is there a way to prevent code duplication given that the animation storyboards are the same (for focus and for fade) and that more menus will come. I duplicate it because I need to put the TargetName and is different but I suppose there is another "cleaner" way.

Comment: try `Expression Blend`. it's help you to create animation `as easy as possible`.

Comment: I'm using expression blend. That's how I create the above animations. But it provides no guidance about what I ask.

Comment: `Anivas` Provide good answer. for animation problem you must work on `UserControl CodeBehind` and check for current state of opacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is due to dependency property value [precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx). I haven't found a xamlish way to do this. But with code-behind here is how:

- Subscribe to the storyboard's completed event.
- Look for the menuItems that has been selected and call BeginAnimation on it.
- You can find more infomation on this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493.aspx).

  ```
  private void Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e) 
  { 
      foreach (var menuItem in this.file.Items) 
      { 
          var item = (MenuItem)menuItem; 
          if (item.IsChecked) 
          { 
              item.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, null); 
              item.Opacity = 1; 
          } 
      } 
  }
  ```

  I have looked for IsChecked to say if a menuItem is selected. Use your own methodology if this doesnt suit you.

For question 2 add this to resources and you can get rid of all individual triggers and duplicate storyboards:

```
        <Window.Resources> 
    <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOn"> 
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"> 
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.8"/> 
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames> 
    </Storyboard> 
    <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOff" Completed="Storyboard_Completed"> 
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"> 
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="0.3"/> 
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames> 
    </Storyboard> 
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}"> 
        <Style.Triggers> 
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter" > 
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOn}"/> 
        </EventTrigger> 
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave"> 
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOff}"/> 
        </EventTrigger> 
        </Style.Triggers> 
    </Style> 
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Anivas. 
I try your solution but didn't work. The Storyboard_Completed executes and the line that set the opacity executes. But inspecting with the debugger I see that no matter that I put Documents.Opacity = 1, the opacity just don't change.

Comment: Can you post your latest code after the changes and I will have a look.

Comment: Actually is the same. I consult with an MVP and told me the problem was related with how the code was executed. Once the opacity is set (no matter if within your code or my code) that set is deferred until the storyboard release its lock (doesn't happen within the completed event because of the call hierarchy) and given that the logic that sets the opacity sett it only when its 0.3, once the storyboard executes is still 0.8 so no transformation happens.

Thanks anyway Anivas!